# C++ Creating Objects as Static - advice needed on good practice

Tags: c++, c

I am a mainly C programmer building a prototype on a Raspberry Pi.  I'm making extensive use of some open source C code, but also a Raspberry Pi hardware add on which comes with C++ drivers.  So I need them to work together.  I did some research and got them to work together by writing a C++ function with an extern "C" declaration, compiling this as a shared library and linking it with my C program.

I need the C++ function to instantiate an object the first time it is called and then to be able to interact with this object on subsequent calls to the function.  I was slightly overwhelmed by the instructions for how to create and access C++ objects directly in C, so I tried simply adding "static" before the creation of the object - and interacting with the object through the mediation of the C wrapper.  This seems to working perfectly but I'm slightly worried that this is not routinely given as the answer to the "using C++ objects in C" and so I wonder if I am going to end up with unforeseen problems?  I don't need my code at this stage to be high quality, but I don't want to end up with segmentation errors because I have done something foolish.  Any advice would be really appreciated.

Here is a cut down version to show what I am doing.  In this example I create a simple c++ function that takes an int argument from the calling C program.  If the argument is 0 it creates the objects and sets all the leds in array to 0.  If I call this a second time with the argument = 1, it instructs the same object to light all the red leds.  This code works.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <matrix_hal/everloop.h>
#include <matrix_hal/everloop_image.h>
#include <matrix_hal/matrixio_bus.h>

extern "C" int led_change(int input_from_c)
{
namespace hal = matrix_hal;

static hal::MatrixIOBus bus;
static hal::EverloopImage image1d(18);
static hal::Everloop everloop;

if (input_from_c == 0)
   {
   if (!bus.Init()) return false;
   // this line just resizes the EverloopImage object to the number of LEDs on the board
   everloop.Setup(&bus);
   // switch off the leds
   for (int i=0;i<18;i++)
      {
      image1d.leds[i].red = 0;
      image1d.leds[i].green = 0;
      image1d.leds[i].blue= 0;
      image1d.leds[i].white = 0;
      }
  everloop.Write(&image1d);
   }
   else if (input_from_c == 1)
   {
   for (int i=0;i<18;i++)
      {
      image1d.leds[i].red = 100;
      image1d.leds[i].green = 0;
      image1d.leds[i].blue= 0;
      image1d.leds[i].white = 0;
      }
   everloop.Write(&image1d);
   }
return 1;
}
```

The calling code in C is just

```
#include  <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int led_change (int);
int i;

void main () {
      i = led_change(0);
      printf("returned %d\n",i);
      sleep(1);
      i = led_change(1);
      printf("returned second time %d\n",i);
}
```

Hope this clear.  Thanks for any help.

Comment: I think this may be the first time I've been worried when my code actually works !

Comment: If you show the relevant part of your code, then it will probably make it a lot easier for others to give you (much more accurate) suggestions on it.

Comment: It isn't quite clear what it means "to access C++ objects in C". If the object is essentially a C struct, you don't care that it is created by C++ code. You access it in the same exact way you access any other object. If it is an object that is not compatible with C, you cannot access it from C at all.

Comment: Code now added - apologies.

Answer (score 0):

You need to compile and link all your C code as C++ modules.  The reverse doesn't work.  C doesn't know about constructors to be called for your `static` objects in c++ modules... so the linker has to understand the c++ calling sequences.  C++ language was designed with compatibility of old C code in mind.  But C doesn't have that statement in mind when it was designed.

Despite of this, C++ compilers normally can compile also pure C code (in C language mode) so one of these compilers will be valid.  It will generate code that can survive in the same program without any problem.

You can have a C code `main()` function in a c++ program, but always use a c++ linker to link that code into the program.

Comment: I actually built the whole thing with a make file and the RPI is compiling the c programs as c and the c++ as c++ - but they appear to link and work fine.  I guess I am worrying about nothing.  The system seems to be performant and running without any memory leaks or errors.  I was just surprised how easy it all turned out to be !

Answer (score 0):

When "C" code is linked to C++ code using "extern", C++ compilers stop "name mangling" for those C variables or functions, while creating symbol names in object file. For C++ functions, they mangle names to support function overloading.

When static objects are returned from shared objects, they might create problem in multi-threaded programs, like two or more threads modifying the values in the static objects at the same time.

Comment: Thank you Lorenz - for the replies.  The multi-threaded point is a useful one although it is not an issue for me as I am only calling this one piece of c++ code from a single thread.